# Can not find a control using the FindControl on RowCreated for Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, findcontrol

I am using a gridview, and here is one of my templatefields:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity" SortExpression="Quantity">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:Label ToolTip="Quantity" runat="server" Text="Qty"></asp:Label>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Quantity" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Quantity") %>' Width="30px"
            Enabled='True'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I am tring to reach txt_Quantity like this

```
    protected void begv_OrderDetail_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txt_Quantity = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txt_Quantity");
        txt_Quantity.Attributes.Add("onFocus", "test(this)");
    }
```

This is the error message:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RowCreated` is executed for every [`RowType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowtype.aspx)(btw, the same as with `RowDataBound`), so for the header, data-row, footer or pager.

The first row is the header-row, but the `TextBox` is in rows with `RowType`=[`DataRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolrowtype.aspx). Since it's in the `EditItemTemplate` you also have to check the [`EditIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.editindex.aspx):

```
protected void begv_OrderDetail_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow
       && e.Row.RowIndex == begv_OrderDetail.EditIndex)
    {
        TextBox txt_Quantity = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txt_Quantity");
        txt_Quantity.Attributes.Add("onFocus", "test(this)");
    }
}
```

Note that if you enumerate the [`Rows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rows.aspx) property of the `GridView` you only get the rows with `RowType`=`DataRow`, so the header, footer and pager are omitted. So here no additional check is needed:

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in begv_OrderDetail.Rows)
{
    // only DataRows
}
```